# WithClauseError, elixir unit tests match with (:ok, value}

Tags: testing, functional-programming, elixir, tdd, with-statement

I'm trying to write safe functional code in elixir and use unit tests to confirm my code works correctly.  Here is the controller code:

```
def calculate_price(start_time, end_time, zone, payment_type) do
    with( {:ok} <- validate_times(start_time, end_time),
          {:ok} <- validate_zone(zone),
          {:ok} <- validate_payment_type(payment_type)
    ) do
      elapsed_minutes = div(Time.diff(end_time, start_time), 60)
      cond do
        zone == "A" && elapsed_minutes <= 15 -> {:ok, 0}
        zone == "B" && elapsed_minutes <= 90 -> {:ok, 0}
        zone == "A" && elapsed_minutes > 15 && payment_type == "hourly" -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 15, 2, 60)}
        zone == "B" && elapsed_minutes > 90 && payment_type == "hourly" -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 90, 1, 60)}
        zone == "A" && elapsed_minutes > 15 && payment_type == "real"   -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 15, 0.16, 5)}
        zone == "B" && elapsed_minutes > 90 && payment_type == "real"   -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 90, 0.08, 5)}
      end
    else
      {:error, error} -> IO.puts error
    end
  end

  defp validate_times(start_time, end_time) when end_time > start_time, do: :ok
  defp validate_times(_start_time, _end_time), do: {:error, "The start/end time is wrong"}

  defp validate_zone(zone) when zone == "A" or zone == "B", do: :ok
  defp validate_zone(_zone), do: {:error, "The zone is wrong"}

  defp validate_payment_type(payment_type) when payment_type == "hourly" or payment_type == "real", do: :ok
  defp validate_payment_type(_payment_type), do: {:error, "The payment type is wrong"}

  defp calc(minutes_to_pay, price_per_minutes, minutes_per_price_increment) do
    cond do
      rem(minutes_to_pay, minutes_per_price_increment) > 0 ->
        (div(minutes_to_pay, minutes_per_price_increment) + 1) * price_per_minutes
      true -> div(minutes_to_pay, minutes_per_price_increment) * price_per_minutes
    end
  end
```

controller_test code:

```
test "calculate price; zone: B, paymentType: real" do
    # 4 hours and 30 minute difference
    startTime = ~T[12:00:00.000]
    endTime = ~T[16:30:00.000]
    zone = "B"
    paymentType = "real"

   assert {:ok, 2.88} == calculate_price(startTime, endTime, zone, paymentType)

  end
```

For this code, I'm tring to validate the correct parameters are passed in so that on the happy path of my code I return a result of `{:ok, value}`.  If the parameters are wrong I want to know why the error happened.  Currently I am just printing to command line, but eventually I want to return `{:error, reason}`. Just putting `{:error, error}` in the else clause caused a different error.

The result of the test case is:
`** (WithClauseError) no with clause matching: :ok`

What I think this means is that my calculate_price function is returning `{:ok}`.  I don't understand why the value inside the `with` clause is being returned and not the values in the `do` or `else` clause!

My elixir version is 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
{:ok} <- validate_times(start_time, end_time)
```

The method returns bare `:ok` atom, while you attempt to pattern match it to the single element tuple `{:ok}` in `with`, what obviously fails.

That would work:

```rb
with :ok <- validate_times(start_time, end_time),
     :ok <- validate_zone(zone),
     :ok <- validate_payment_type(payment_type) do
  ...
end
```

Also, use `mix format` task to format your code according to the guidelines, otherwise it’s extremely hard to read.
This applies to the subsequent clauses in `with` as well.

---

*Sidenote:* that’s how we might use pattern matching and guards to rewrite your `cond` clause in more elixirish way:

```rb
case {zone, elapsed_minutes, payment_type} do
  {"A", elapsed_minutes, _} when elapsed_minutes <= 15 -> {:ok, 0}
  {"B", elapsed_minutes, _} when elapsed_minutes <= 90 -> {:ok, 0}
  {"A", _, "hourly"} -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 15, 2, 60)}
  {"B", _, "hourly"} -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 90, 1, 60)}
  {"A", _, "real"} -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 15, 0.16, 5)}
  {"B", _, "real"} -> {:ok, calc(elapsed_minutes - 90, 0.08, 5)}
end
```

Comment: I just figured out that the problem was the {:ok} did not match with the :ok I was returning.  
Your case statement looks much cleaner than my cond statement.  Thank you for the tip on how to improve my elixir code.

Answer (score 1):

First check if your code works manually. From the error message, I believe that your code has an error somewhere in the logic and never returns `{:ok, ...}`. It probably is the `Datetime`. You usually use `DateTime.compare()` to make the comparison.

The fastest way to check is to pattern match the result to a variable and assert the variable. `Mix` will show you the returned results along with your expected result.

```
result = calculate_price(startTime, endTime, zone, paymentType)
assert result == {:ok, 2.88}
```

Comment: Any text that contains “probably” and “believe” should be a comment, not an answer. From the code above it’s evident what the issue is and it’s not what you believe it is.